# Spring boot - Autowire datasource

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, datasource

I am having a spring boot application using gradle , I am trying to inject a datasource , based on the information given in application.properties(under src/main/resources)

```
 spring.datasource.url=
 spring.datasource.username=
 spring.datasource.password=
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I have sqljdbc4.jar in my classpath , And in my boot class (the one annotated with @SpringBootApplication , I have 
a field of type javax.sql.Datasource annotated with @Autowired . But that field is not getting autowired and it complains about missing bean definition . Ideally i want SqlServerXADatasource to be injected into this field . Spring boot should ideally autowire it based on the info given in application.properties , right ? What am i missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried using @Autowired on a field of type Datasource?

Comment: Sorry , the question had a mistake . Corrected it now. Please reread it

Comment: You did add the correct dependencies to your classpath did you? Maybe post your ``build.gradle`` so we can look for what might be missing. Spring Boot will not just create a ``Datasource`` if there is no dependency triggering autoconfiguration.

Comment: /@Bean
    /@Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(/@Value("${spring.datasource.url}") String url, /@Value("${spring.datasource.username}") String userName, /@Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String password, /@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") Class<? extends Driver> driver) {
     SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
     ds.setDriverClass(driver);
     ds.setUsername(userName);
     ds.setUrl(url);
     ds.setPassword(password);
     return ds;
    }

add this to your JavaConfig @SpringApplication class and add a breakpoint to help debug.

Comment: buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
 compile fileTree(dir: "/lib", includes: ['*.jar'])
 compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.1.RELEASE')
 compile('org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.1.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

Comment: Above is my gradle script split in twocomments . compile fileTree(dir: "/lib", includes: ['*.jar']) - this line makes sure my lib directory is in the classpath . And i have sqljdbc4.jar in lib directory .

Comment: Hello , any suggestions ?